# How to crawl links to a particular domain by searching on Google?

Tags: python, web-crawler, data-mining, scrapy

I have a corpus of lyrics of Indian songs and need to tag them with their year of release for an experiment I am working on.

There is a website(lyricsindia.net), which has an exhaustive database of these lyrics with years, but unfortunately the lyrics cannot be searched on the website. Instead, when I google with part of lyrics as the search string, the link to the song on lyricsindia.net is always in the top-10 results.

Now, I was wondering if it was possible using web-crawling frameworks like scrapy to use a search-string as a starting point for crawling. Every Scrapy tutorial, I have come across starts with a starting URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search string could be a part of the url with Scrapy. something like google.com?q=my+string

Or, you can retrieve the search form, and fill it with your string, something like :

```
return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'search': 'you\'re search string'},
            callback=self.parse)]
```

I'm sure Scrapy might do what you want to do.